# Smudge in scan mid page when using adf

Tags: printer, scanning

I have an OKI printer/scanner that needed to be cleaned.  I managed to get all the lines taken care of but about half way down the scanned page, and only when using the ADF, there is a smudge.  It doesn't go the length of the page, its almost like the paper isn't making complete contact half way through the scan.  Anyone have any ideas on how i fix this or even if it can be fixed?

The printer is an OKI MB470.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a scan of a page with the smudge?  When you say you cleaned it, did you also clean and examine the ADF pickup and feed rollers?

Comment: I did clean all the rollers I could find and anywhere where I though the page would be coming into contact with a surface.  I don't have  enough rep to post image, try this link: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C4BD9059A0C5422B!805&authkey=!AJW4MQalcV1490E&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.gif

Comment: I posted your picture for you.  Did you see my question regarding the condition of the rollers?

Comment: It seems to be picking up the page OK.  Maybe its a bit touchy if its been fiddled with, but if left alone its picking up a single page just fine.  I'll go take another look at the rollers.

Comment: Well all the rollers seem ok.  Unless someone else has any suggestions I guess I'm going to have to chalk this up to wear.